# Type erasure, passing Class in argument

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

When I call:

```
ArrayList<MyType> myobject = new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());
```

everything works properly, using the `fromJson(String, Type)`
when I call:

```
ArrayList<MyType> myobject = helper(data);

public ArrayList<MyType> helper(String data){
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyType>>(){}.getType());
}
```

it still works fine, but when I call :

```
ArrayList<MyType> myobject = helper(data, MyType.class);

public <T> ArrayList<T> helper(String data, Class<T> type){
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());
}
```

the type argument is not proper.
How can I fix the last code snippet?

**SOLUTION**

As @LewsTherin proposed, I simply gave the exact Type in argument from caller
so helper declaration is so:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> helper(String data, Type type){
    ArrayList<T> rtn = g.fromJson(data, type);
    return rtn;
}
```

and call like:

```
variable = helper(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyType>>(){}.getType());
```

**But if anybody can edit helper function to simplify the code, I will mark him as correct for sure!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would work if you use  in helper function. The solution might be to pass the type from the calling method. So it is clear what is happening.

```
return new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType());
```

This is not actually specifying the object Class type. Hence why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go about handling this would be to parse the list your self from GSON:

```
private <S> List<S> readFromJson(Reader input, Class<S> type) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement element = parser.parse(input);
    ImmutableList.Builder<S> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    for (JsonElement jsonElement : element.getAsJsonArray()) {
        builder.add(fromJson(jsonElement));
    }
    return builder.build();
}

private <S> S fromJson(JsonElement jsonElement, Class<S> type) {
    return configReader.fromJson(jsonElement, type);
}
```

Additionally, the GSON documentation has an example similar to what you are trying to accomplish: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-InstanceCreator-for-a-Parameterized